# Other Threads stops when one thread reaches its destination

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans

I am currently working on understanding the Java concept of multithreading. I went through a tutorial which uses the Tortoise and the Hare example to explain the concept of multithreading, and to a large extent I understood the syntax and the logic of the video tutorial. At the end of the video tutorial, the Youtuber gave an assignment that involves applying Multithreading to an olympic race track.

Using my knowledege from the example, I was able to create 10 threads (representing the athletes) that run within a loop, that executes 100 times (representing 100 meters).

My challenge is that when the Thread scheduler makes an Athlete to get to 100 meters before the other 9 athletes, the remaining 9 threads always do not complete their race. This is not usually the case in a standard race track. The fact that a Thread called Usain Bolts gets to 100 first, does not mean Yohan Blake should stop running if he is at 90m at that time.

I am also interested in getting the distance (note that they are all using the same variable) for each thread, so that I can use a function to return the positions of each Thread at the end of the race.

What I have done (that did not work):
 1) I have tried to use an if else construct (containing nine "else"
 statement) to assign the distance of each executing thread to a new integer variable. (using the Thread.currentThread().getName() property and the name of each thread) but that did not work well for me. This was an attempt to give positions to the athletes alone using their distance but does nothing about the 9 athletes not finishing the race.
2) I have also tried to use an ArrayList to populate the distance at runtime but for some strange reasons this still overwrites the distance each time it wants to add another distance.

Below are my codes:

```
package olympics100meters;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HundredMetersTrackRules implements Runnable {
public static String winner;

public void race() {
for (int distance=1;distance<=50;distance++) {
System.out.println("Distance covered by "+Thread.currentThread    ().getName  ()+" is "+distance+" meters.");


boolean isRaceWon=this.isRaceWon(distance);
if (isRaceWon) {
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
numbers.add(distance);
System.out.println("testing..."+numbers);
break;
}

}
}


private boolean isRaceWon(int totalDistanceCovered) {
   boolean isRaceWon=false;
   if ((HundredMetersTrackRules.winner==null)&&    (totalDistanceCovered==50)) {
   String winnerName=Thread.currentThread().getName();
   HundredMetersTrackRules.winner=winnerName;
   System.out.println("The winner is "+HundredMetersTrackRules.winner);
   isRaceWon=true;
   }

   else if (HundredMetersTrackRules.winner==null) {
   isRaceWon=false;
   }

   else if (HundredMetersTrackRules.winner!=null) {
   isRaceWon=true;
   }
   return isRaceWon;
}

public void run() {
this.race();
}     
}
```

This is my main method (I reduced it to 5 Athletes till I sort out the issues):

```
public class Olympics100Meters {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   HundredMetersTrackRules racer=new HundredMetersTrackRules();
   Thread UsainBoltThread=new Thread(racer,"UsainBolt");
   Thread TysonGayThread=new Thread (racer,"TysonGay");
   Thread AsafaPowellThread=new Thread(racer,"AsafaPowell");
   Thread YohanBlakeThread=new Thread (racer,"YohanBlake");
   Thread JustinGatlinThread=new Thread (racer,"JustinGatlin");

   UsainBoltThread.start();
   TysonGayThread.start();
   AsafaPowellThread.start();
   YohanBlakeThread.start();
   JustinGatlinThread.start();

 }
}
```

Comment: Array list isn't thread safe. I don't see synchronized key word normally used for concurrency... I am not show how you are handling the race other than arraylist perhaps use blockingqueue or something that is safe or use the key work synchronized

Comment: If you want to write flexible and robust multi-threading code, you should definitely avoid addressing the  Thread class directly.  Use Runnable to define your tasks, and make them execute via an ExecutorService. You will then be able to control the execution flow and stop conditions. There are numerous examples of the ExecutorService usages on the net.

Comment: Thank you. But is there a way I can make this program do what I want it to do by using the Thread class directly? I want to be sure of the fundamental concepts in Multithreading.

Comment: I am afraid you will need to post more code in order for us to find the problem. Yes, it is possible to do it by using the `Thread` class directly, but first heed the warning that `ArrayList` is not thread safe, and wrap it inside a thread-safe collection wrapper.

Comment: `List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());`

Comment: Please format your code, and also tell us exactly what you expected to see on the screen, and exactly what you see instead.  (How do you know that the remaining 9 threads always do not complete their race? You *think* that's the case, but let us judge that.)

Comment: Thank you. I will do just that. I will also provide the code for my first algorithm (trying to use the getname() property to get each distance). I already overwrite it when saving again. But the battery of my laptop is currently down and I need to get it powered for some time. And I will be going offline soon. Please can this question be put on hold? Thanks.

Comment: @CYNTHIA Blessing If you are okay with this. Could you provide me the link from where you are learning this? this is interesting. I want to do this exercise. Please ignore if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

1. > My challenge is that ... the remaining 9 threads always do not complete their race.

This is caused by `isRaceWon()` method implementation. You check for it at each meter at each runner. As soon as the first runner achieves 100 meters, the `break` is called on next step of each runner loop (the race is won for every loop

btw, it makes sense to use `volatile statuc String` for winner's name, to avoid java's memory model ambiguities.

2. > I am also interested in getting the distance ... for each thread, so that I can use a function to return the positions of each Thread at the end of the race.

If the final aim is to get the position, create a class field `public List<String> finishingOrder = new ArrayList<String>` and a method `finish`

```
private synchronized finish() {
   finishingOrder.add(Thread.currentThread().getName())
}
```

and call it after the "run" loop

do not forget to call `join()` for all runner threads in your `main`. After that, the `finishingOrder` will contain names in order of finishing.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below is causing `isRaceWon` to return true for *every* instance of `HundredMetersTrackRules` as soon as the shared `winner` field is set to non-null (i.e. someone wins.):

```
else if (HundredMetersTrackRules.winner!=null) {
   isRaceWon=true;
}
```

This in turn causes the loop in `race()` to break for every instance of your `Runnable`.  The `run()` method exits, terminating the thread.

The issue is just a logic error and not really specific to threading.  But, as other posters have mentioned, there's some threading best-practices you can also adopt in this code, such as using `volatile` for fields shared by threads.

Answer (score 0):

Actually For Race you need to start all the Threads at once then only its Race.
`CountDownLatch` is better one to Implement or write Race Program.

Many other way also we can write Race program without using the `CountDownLatch`.
If we need to implement using base / low level then we can use `volatile` boolean Flag and counter variable in synchronized blocks or using `wait()` and `notifyAll()` logic, etc.,

Introduced some time delay in your program inside the for loop. Then only you can feel the Experience. Why because you are not starting all the threads at once.

Hope you are Practicing Initial / base Level so I made few changes only for better understanding and Addressed all your queries.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
class HundredMetersTrackRules implements Runnable {
    public static Main main;
    
    HundredMetersTrackRules(Main main){
        this.main=main;
    }
    
    public static String winner;
    public void race() {
        try{
               System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Waiting for others...");
               while(!Main.start){
                    Thread.sleep(3);
               }
            for (int distance=1;distance<=50;distance++) {
                System.out.println("Distance covered by "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is "+distance+" meters.");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            synchronized(main){
                Main.finish--;
            }
            Main.places.add(Thread.currentThread().getName());
         }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();  
         }
    }
    
    public void run() {
    this.race();
    }     
}
public class Main
{
   public static volatile boolean start = false;
   public static int finish = 5;
   final  static List<String> places = 
            Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
   public static void main(String[] args) {
         
   HundredMetersTrackRules racer=new HundredMetersTrackRules(new Main());
   Thread UsainBoltThread=new Thread(racer,"UsainBolt");
   Thread TysonGayThread=new Thread (racer,"TysonGay");
   Thread AsafaPowellThread=new Thread(racer,"AsafaPowell");
   Thread YohanBlakeThread=new Thread (racer,"YohanBlake");
   Thread JustinGatlinThread=new Thread (racer,"JustinGatlin");

   UsainBoltThread.start();
   TysonGayThread.start();
   AsafaPowellThread.start();
   YohanBlakeThread.start();
   JustinGatlinThread.start();
   
   Main.start=true;
   
   while(Main.finish!=0){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();  
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("The winner is "+places.get(0));
    System.out.println("All Places :"+places);
  }
}
```